# SQLite with priority query

Tags: sqlite

I need assistance to fix my problem with a DB Query.
Inside of my database I have some different TV Stations. The most of these stations have different resolutions to offer. i.e. 4K, FHD, HD, SD, .
Now I want to select distinct for each station. This is easy, but I always want to get the row with the highest resolution for this TV Station.

An Example:

```
|DE|ZDF
|DE|ZDF HD
|DE|RTL
|DE|RTL FHD
|DE|RTL HD
|DE|SAT1
```

Output should be:

```
|DE|ZDF HD
|DE|RTL FHD
|DE|SAT1
```

Could you help me out with this?

This is not working as expected:

```
SELECT 
    sender,
    MAX(quality) AS quality
FROM (
    SELECT 
        SUBSTR(tvg_name, 1, INSTR(tvg_name, '|') - 1) AS sender,
        CASE 
            WHEN tvg_name LIKE '%4K' THEN '4K'
            WHEN tvg_name LIKE '%FHD' THEN 'FHD'
            WHEN tvg_name LIKE '%HD' THEN 'HD'
            ELSE 'SD' 
        END AS quality
    FROM derek 
    WHERE tvg_name LIKE '|DE%'
) AS temp
GROUP BY sender;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following (especially the comments):-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS derek;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS derek (tvg_name);
INSERT INTO derek VALUES
    ('|DE|ZDF'),
    ('|DE|ZDF HD'),
    ('|DE|RTL'),
    ('|DE|RTL FHD'),
    ('|DE|RTL HD'),
    ('|DE|SAT1')
;


SELECT 
    tvg_name, /* result data wanted */
    sender, /* ????? see results  and also country_and_station */
    quality, /* see output not sortable (maxable according to resolution) without custom sort/handling as F < S and also less than H */
    MAX(resolution) AS resolution, /* sortable/maxable i.e. converted to resolution */
    country_and_station
FROM (
    SELECT
        tvg_name,
        SUBSTR(tvg_name, 1, INSTR(tvg_name, '|') - 1) AS sender /*????*/,
        CASE 
            WHEN tvg_name LIKE '%4K' THEN '4K'
            WHEN tvg_name LIKE '%FHD' THEN 'FHD'
            WHEN tvg_name LIKE '%HD' THEN 'HD'
            ELSE 'SD' 
        END AS quality,
        /* Added to add column sortable according to screen resolution aka quality */
        CASE 
            WHEN tvg_name LIKE '%4K' THEN 3840 * 2160
            WHEN tvg_name LIKE '%FHD' THEN 1920 * 1080
            WHEN tvg_name LIKE '%HD' THEN 1270 * 720
            ELSE 640 * 480 
        END AS resolution,
        /* better handling of sender i.e. strip quality if quality exists so same for all station quality (!!!!!WARNING!!!!! ASSUMES SPACE BEFORE quality) */
        CASE 
            WHEN instr(tvg_name,' ') THEN substr(tvg_name,1,instr(tvg_name,' ')-1)
            ELSE tvg_name
        END AS country_and_station
    FROM derek
    WHERE tvg_name LIKE '|DE%'
) AS temp
GROUP BY country_and_station
ORDER BY resolution DESC
;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS derek;
```

The result of the above (which has additional columns to show the intermediate results/columns), using the data as you have shown, is:-

[image]

- i.e. according to what you say the output should be (1st column).

Of course using a single column for multiple data is frowned upon due to the complexities involved. A column per data (country,station,quality) would greatly simplify the above.

e.g. Say you were to have:-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS derek2 (country,station,quality);
INSERT INTO derek2 VALUES
    ('DE','ZDF',''),
    ('DE','ZDF','HD'),
    ('DE','RTL',''),
    ('DE','RTL','FHD'),
    ('DE','RTL','HD'),
    ('DE','SAT1','')
;
```

- i.e. 3 columns for the data that you have

  - even simpler if you say converted the quality into a sortable version of the quality such as the resolution.

Then you could use, the simpler:-

```
SELECT '|'||country||'|'||station||' '||quality AS tvg_name, 
    MAX( CASE 
        WHEN quality = '4K'  THEN 3840 * 2160
        WHEN quality = 'FHD' THEN 1920 * 1080
        WHEN quality = 'HD' THEN 1270 * 720
        ELSE 640 * 480
    END) AS resolution
FROM derek2
WHERE country = 'DE'
GROUP BY  station
ORDER BY resolution DESC
;
```

Which would then produce:-

[image]